# Java Spring Swagger Startuptime Startupbehaviour

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox

I am having a Springboot application where I integrated Swagger for creating REST documentations.

When using swagger my startup time increases dramatically by factor 5. I'm having 30secs without swagger. 2min plus with swagger.

Also having the docket listed in the snipped underneath startup time becomes endlessly! - And this is a no-go.

My Problem is endless startup times + Exceptions regarding memory usage from google guava.

Why is it that way? What am I doing wrong? Where is the missing point? Why is the API not protecting me from very wrong setups?

It feels like that swagger is on the one hand a number one tool for documenting rest APIs but using it feels very ancient for me.

Some setup info (located at maven pom.xml):
- org.springframework.boot; spring-boot-starter-parent; 1.5.5.RELEASE
- io.springfox; springfox-swagger2; 2.9.2
- io.springfox; springfox-swagger-ui; 2.9.2

I somewhere picked up that googles guava library needs to be exchanged; which I did: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2616#issuecomment-412811912

Is swagger/springfox really so good to use for documenting an API coming from Spring? - What would be some alternatives to render documentation?

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class Swagger2UiConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  ...
  @Bean(name="restPublicSwaggerV1Api")
  public Docket publicV1Api(BuildProperties build) {

    final ApiInfoBuilder apiInfo = new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title(build.getName())
            .description("Description for public API")
            .version( build.getVersion() );

    final long TIME = System.currentTimeMillis();

    final Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName( "public-v1" )
            .apiInfo( apiInfo.build() )
            .select()
            .apis( (wmrh)->{ // springfox.documentation.spring.web.WebMvcRequestHandler

                final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                sb.append( wmrh.getClass().getTypeName()  +"\n\t"+ wmrh );
                final RequestHandlerKey rhk = wmrh.key();

                boolean result = false;

                for( String pathMapping : rhk.getPathMappings() ) {
                    sb.append( "\n\t-> "+ pathMapping );
                    result |= pathMapping.startsWith( "/api/public/" );
                }

                sb.append( "\n\t=>> "+ result +", time: "+ Util.formatTime( System.currentTimeMillis() - TIME ) +" after start." );

                LOG.debug( sb.toString() );

                return result;
            } )
            .paths( (p)->{ return true; } )
            .build();

    LOG.debug( "instantiated: {}", docket );
    return docket;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using latest swagger-ui(swagger-js 2.1.17) as specified in

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1919

Comment: I will have a look. First comment starts at 27 Jan 2016. Thank you...
I would be interested if anyone is seriously using it on java / spring.

Comment: Am I not using 2.9.2 which is higher? If I get it right you are talking about some js-library (I guess since swagger-js 2.1.17 is mentioned). The I am having problem occures on the java start and does not deal with displaying it in a browser. It more deals with swagger/springfox collecting data for creating a gui/html in order to display.

Comment: swagger-ui version 3.18.3

Comment: Hey Mebin, I get confused... I am running java/spring on a maven setup where I reference io.springfox libraries. Their max versioning goes currently to 2.9.2 as seeable here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 Do you have another way to set it up? Which would be the maven settings then. Where to look it up? See here how the libs are referenced within maven's pom.xml: https://pastebin.com/9WMr1fET

Answer (score 0):

Use @JsonIgnore in Many-To-Many relations

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).